# Select textbox on focus, deselect on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, focus, onblur

I am trying to select a textbox that has my link to this page url in it.  I use:

```
$('.linkTo').focus(function() {
    this.select();
});

$('.linkTo').blur(function() {
    var input_value = this.value;
    this.value = input_value;   
});
```

But it only works the first time, the second time it puts a deselected cursor where I clicked.

Comment: deselect cursor - nothing is selected and a cursor is there where i clicked in the textbox

Comment: Does you answer work if you enter the text box by tabbing?

Comment: Just tested it - if you enter a text box by tabbing it selects everything anyway - whether you write code or not.

Comment: thx everyone for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foucusin()` and `focusout()`

http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 0):

Solution edited out from the question:

```
<input onclick="this.select();" class.... />
```